# Jquery ajax parameter is undefined in the PHP script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm using jQuery Ajax to send parameters to a PHP script. Below is the Jquery ajax script

```
  jQuery
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#builder_group").change(function () {
        var selected_builder = $(this).val();
        alert(selected_builder);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'getGroupzCode.php',
            data: 'selected_builder',
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                // Call this function on success                
                console.log(data);
                var yourArray = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(yourArray);
                $.each(yourArray, function (index, yourArray) {
                    $('#builder_group1').append($('<option/>', {
                        value: yourArray.id,
                        text: yourArray.name,
                    }));
                });
            },
            error: function () {
                displayDialogBox('Error', err.toString());
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

When I see in firebug console I see the parametr passed is correct as selected but in the PHP script I see undefined index

```
PHP
    $builder_id=$_POST['selected_builder'];
    error_log($builder_id);
```

Comment: You are sending datatype as json so PHP expects to read json from data, which is merely text. Change accordingly. Either change datatype to text or change data to a json object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data: 'selected_builder',
```

That is not proper format. You need:

```
data: { selected_builder: selected_builder }
```

The below indicates you're receiving a json, is that correct? If so the parameter is "dataType" like below.

```
dataType: 'json',
```

If so you are you would use this in your php file:

```
$encoded = json_encode($yourvariable);
echo $encoded;
```

Now if this wasn't the case you would call the variable in php by:

```
$variable = $_POST["selected_builder"];
```

Comment: But can refresh the dropdown everytime